# Naive Bayes Classification problem - ValueError: domain math error

Tags: python, math, logging

I am trying to classify unseen tweets using a multinomial naive bayes model. I'm getting an error and can't figure out how to fix it. ValueError: math domain error. The error is occurring when using math.log function. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
def calcWordProbability(newTweet, dictionary):
    V = len(dictionary)
    countC = sum(dictionary.values())
    sumOfProbs = 0
    for word in newTweet:
        if (word in dictionary):
            x = (dictionary.get(word)+1) / (countC + V) 
            sumOfProbs = sumOfProbs + math.log(x)
    return sumOfProbs

def classification(tweet):
    totalNegTweets = 0
    for line in trainNegData:
        totalNegTweets += 1
    totalPosTweets = 0
    for line in trainPosData:
        totalPosTweets += 1 

    totalNumOfTweets = totalNegTweets + totalPosTweets
    positiveOverTotal = totalPosTweets / totalNumOfTweets
    negativeOverTotal = totalNegTweets / totalNumOfTweets

    positive = (math.log(positiveOverTotal)) + (calcWordProbability(tweet,posDict))
    negative = (math.log(negativeOverTotal)) + (calcWordProbability(tweet,negDict))

    if(positive < negative):
        prediction = 0
    else:
        prediction = 1

    return prediction
```

problem is occurring in lines:

```
positive = (math.log(positiveOverTotal))+(calcWordProbability(tweet,posDict))
negative = (math.log(negativeOverTotal))+(calcWordProbability(tweet,negDict))
```

Comment: please excuse my question formatting, first post.

Comment: I'm guessing this because the argument you're passing to the logarithm function is 0. `math.log` is not defined at 0. Have you checked to see if `negativeOverTotal` or `positiveOverTotal` are non-zero before passing to the logarithm function?

Comment: As your question is in Python, your formatting really matters. Please try and correct it. Also, your `return sumOfProbs` is returning from what? Did you missed part of your code when copying and pasting?

Comment: @AuroraWang code has been corrected it should make more sense now

Comment: turns out I was trying to find log of 0 after all, true problem was occurring before the math.log ! Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when a class or feature appear in no samples at all.

Using `numpy.log` instead of `math.log` will produce a warning instead of an exception when trying to get the logarithm of zero.

But I strongly suggest using sklearn's `MultinomialNB`: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB